# SQL Function takes an sql string, execute the string and returns the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-function

I've done a lot of functions that return a table but somehow this one keeps on giving me an error at `Begin` and I couldn't figure out for the life of me why.  My `where` statement is stored in a table.  This function I want to pass in a value and the where statement.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Testtesttest(@employeeID        AS INT,
                                 @sqlWhereStatement AS VARCHAR(max))
Returns TABLE
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @mySQLStatement VARCHAR(max)

      SET @mySQLStatement = 'Set Quoted_Identifier OFF Select '
                           + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @employeeID) + ',* from (
        select m.ManagerID, m.Name,m.Email,e.BU,
        e.PSC from m inner join e on m.ManagerID = e.EmployeeID
        group by m.ManagerID, m.Name,m.Email,e.BU,e.SC,
        e.PSC) x where ' + @sqlWhereStatement

      EXEC(@mySQLStatement)

      RETURN
  END
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't use dynamic SQL in a function so what you are trying to do is not possible via a TSQL TVF.

Maybe a CLR UDF can do something like this but I would find a different approach anyway.

Comment: if have i have function returning a complete sql string, can I do this  exec(myFunctionThatReturnSQLString)  but sadly this won't work as well. :(  any thoughts?

Comment: @chungtinhlakho - You haven't really explained your root problem. Just your proposed solution, which isn't possible, but [probably something here will help.](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just wrap that logic in a stored procedure? If you need to take the results of sproc into a table, you can use INSERT INTO EXEC

```
INSERT INTO
yourTable(col1, col2, col3)
EXEC Testtesttest @employeeID, @sqlWhereStatement
```